# Why pyhton is not able to find a scrapy generated package?

Tags: python, windows, import, scrapy

> ```
> Platform: Windows 10.
> IDE: v.s. code
> Python version: 3.12.1
> Scrapy version: 2.11.0
> ```

I generated a scrapy project using a terminal with:

```
scrapy startprojet NewScrapyProject
```

After that I went to the items.py file and modified the existing item:

```
import scrapy

class MyItem(scrapy.Item):
    field1 = scrapy.Field()
    field2 = scrapy.Field()
```

Then I created a new spider in the spiders folder within a new_síder.py file, gave it a name, imported the item, defined the parse method, and created an instance of the spider:

```
from NewScrapyProject.items import MyItem
from scrapy.spiders import CrawlSpider

class NewSpider(CrawlSpider):
    name='my_spyder'

    def parse(self, response):
        item = MyItem()
        item['field1'] = response.xpath('//div[1]//ul/li').get()
        item['field2'] = response.xpath('//div[1]//ul//li[2]').get()
        yield item

spider = NewSpider()
print(spider.name)
```

(Don't get confused here, scrapy generates a root folder and a package inside, both with the same name)

Finally, I just hit play to see if everything was ok till this point. But:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):File"c:\Users\USER\Documents\pythonProjects\NewScrapyProject\NewScrapyProject\spiders\new_spider.py", line 1, in <module>from NewScrapyProject.items import MyItemModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'NewScrapyProject'
```

I changed files and folder names, cleared the cache, changed to python 3.10.2, relative imports (from ..items)...

I just started I cannot go beyond! help!

Comment: change import from `from NewScrapyProject.items import MyItem` to `from .items import MyItem`

Comment: When I try relative imports the error is:

ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package

Comment: use `from items import MyItem` had a dot by mistake

Answer (score 0):

I just had to create a ".py" file in the root folder of the project (name it as you please). I jus cut the code to instantiate a new spider and print its name from where it was, and pasted it in this new file. Like this:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    spider = NewSpider()
    print(spider.name)
```

Don't forget to import the NewSpider class